# How list comprehensions are evaluated in python and in what order

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two list comprehensions where conditions are defined in different places.

```
>>> [ x**2 if x%2==0 else x**3 if x%3==0 else 0 for x in range(10)]
[0, 0, 4, 27, 16, 0, 36, 0, 64, 729]

>>> [ x**2 if x%2==0 for x in range(10) ]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [ x**2 if x%2==0 for x in range(10) ]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However if i do this:

```
>>> [ x**2 for x in range(10) if x%2==0 ]
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
>>>
```

it works.

Now the confusing part is how the order is evaluated. What is the difference?

Comment: the else is not optional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two different concepts confused here.

An expression like `x**2 if x%2==0 else x**3` is a *conditional expression*. They can be chained, but the `else` is **not optional** - because this is a self-contained expression that evaluates to a single, specific value. The `else x**3` is required because Python has to know what the expression evaluates to whenever it is not the case that `x % 2 == 0`.

In a *list comprehension*, when you write things like `[x**2 for x in range(10) if x%2==0]`, the `if` clause is used to *filter* the `x` values found `in range(10)`, `for` which elements of the resulting list are computed. There is no `else` permitted here because the purpose is entirely different.

You can mix and match: `[x**2 if x%2 == 0 else x**3 for x in range(10) if x%3 == 0]`. Now `if x % 3 == 0` is being used to decide which `x` values to compute a result for, and `if x%2 == 0` is being used to decide *whether* to use `x**2` or `x**3` as the computed result for those `x`s.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two completely different constructs.

Conditions for list comprehensions can be defined only at one plance, at the end, and they act like *filters*:

```
[ ... for ... if .... ]
```

The other construct you see is python's version of the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/650405). It's not a filter, it just selects one of the expressions based on the logical value of a third expression:

```
... if ... else ...
```

Comment: `if` in the list comprehension can be placed anywhere except before the first `for`: `[x for x in [1,2,3] if x < 2 if x < 4 for j in  [x]]`

Comment: It's not a [nested comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The
>   result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in
>   the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.

so, by definition the `if` comes after the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

For example, this:

```
[ x**2 if x%2==0 else x**3 if x%3==0 else 0 for x in range(10)]
```

Is the equivalent of this:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for x in range(10):
...     l.append(x**2 if x%2==0 else x**3 if x%3==0 else 0)
... 
>>> l
[0, 0, 4, 27, 16, 0, 36, 0, 64, 729]
```

I.e. there is no `if` statement, but rather an `if` expression. So there's always something appended to the list on every step of the `for`.

However when you do this:

```
[ x**2 for x in range(10) if x%2==0 ]
```

And `if` statement will be used. And not all steps will append to the list. Translated into:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for x in range(10):
...     if x%2==0:
...             l.append(x**2)
... 
>>> l
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```