# check if variable is string in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list:

`v = ['4/29/2016 8:25:58 AM', '5/25/2016 2:22:22 PM', 'True', 'Foo', 1, '4/20/1969 4:19:59 PM']`

and i would like to iterate through all of the items, replace `/` with `-` using `re.sub`, and skip the element if it is not a string. What am i doing wrong syntactically in this list comprehension to check if `x` is a string prior to running my `re.sub` ?

`blah = [ re.sub("/", '-', x ) if isinstance(x, str) for x in v ]`

Error output:

```
    blah = [ re.sub("/", '-', x ) if isinstance(x, str) for x in v ]
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25831506/2301450

Answer (score 2):

The `if` clause for the `for` iterations should come after the `for`:

```
>>> blah = [re.sub("/", '-', x ) for x in v if isinstance(x, str)]
>>> blah
['4-29-2016 8:25:58 AM', '5-25-2016 2:22:22 PM', 'True', 'Foo', '4-20-1969 4:19:59 PM']
```

And in your case, since it's a simple substitution you don't need to use `re.sub()`. Use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead:

```
>>> blah = [x.replace('/', '-') for x in v if isinstance(x, str)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `if` and `for` clauses in the wrong order--the `for` clause comes before the `if` clause. Try

```
blah = [ re.sub("/", '-', x ) for x in v if isinstance(x, str) ]
```

I then get for `blah`,

```
['4-29-2016 8:25:58 AM',
 '5-25-2016 2:22:22 PM',
 'True',
 'Foo',
 '4-20-1969 4:19:59 PM']
```